# Create a matrix with strings and numeric values in memory

Tags: string, matrix, stata, numeric, mat

I want both string and numeric values in a matrix. I do not want to create a new dataset because in my real code, I have to keep the dataset loaded, so I have to fill this matrix with numeric and string values in the memory. My real code is more complicated but here is what I tried:

```
clear all
set more off

mat          output_mat  = J(6,5,.)
mat colnames output_mat = method method_name length_dif sector beta

forval x=1/6{

mat output_mat[`x',1]= 1
mat output_mat[`x',2]= "Differences"

}

type mismatch
r(109);
```

What I want to get is something like this:

```
         method  method_name   length_dif       sector         beta
r1          1  "Diferrences"            .            .            .
r2          1  "Diferrences"            .            .            .
r3          1  "Diferrences"            .            .            .
r4          1  "Diferrences"            .            .            .
r5          1  "Diferrences"            .            .            .
r6          1  "Diferrences"            .            .            .
```

Comment: Can't be done. See https://www.stata.com/manuals/u14.pdf for the definition of a Stata matrix as containing numbers. You need something else.

Comment: Thanks, but is there any other tool I can use, like a table or Mata? and then combining the numerical columns with the character columns

Comment: The closest I have ever got to solving what you are looking for is to use locals if I really need to use Stata. In your case they would be called `r1`, `r2` etc. where the value of `r1` would be `` `" "1" "Differences" "." "." "." "' ``. Which is terrible, so if I am solving a task that needs a 2D list, then, if possible, I would use Python.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have to use stata, It is not the most elegant way, but I´m using locals to create a new dataset, and preserve and restore with my loaded data.

Comment: I can't grasp your underlying problem of needing "to keep the dataset loaded".